# Keep state of VideoView while launching new Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview

I have a VideoView that I pause when user click on a button (Launching new Activity) but while user press back and finishing the current Activity I a see black screen of VideoView (Probably its Surface gets killed) and also the video loads again in OnPrepareListener() function (While user paused the video before).

I do not override OnPause() and OnResume().

How can I keep the instance of the VideoView unattached or undestoryed so when usercomes back to the activity he will be in the same state of VideoView was before leaving that Activity ? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `startActivityForResult(.....)` to call new Activity .
And use

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

to listening result while user press back and finishing the current Activity